# Angular ui-router $location

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, wordpress

I'm trying to implement Angular ui-router on a wordpress single page template. This is my app.js:

```
angular
    .module('app', [
    'ui.router'
])

.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state ('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '../../wp-content/themes/my_theme/templates/home.html'
        })
        .state ('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: '../../wp-content/themes/my_theme/templates/about.html'
        })
}])
```

Now my question is: how can I replace my `templateUrl` with the Angular `$location.path()` function in order to make my script more stable?

Comment: `$location.path()` is for angular's routes, not for template urls. Those are not the same thing.

Comment: So it's the wrong way to go, I guess? Is there any other way to implement my wordpress template directory into this javascript?

Comment: Is there a problem with `templateUrl` being unstable?  Can you elaborate on why it could be unstable in your implemenation?

Comment: I tend to upload my wordpress theme with ongoing numbers eachtime I reupload because otherwise it has some issues with remaining files in the wordpress cache. Until this point it wasn't a problem because all my template urls were flexible and I would like to keep it that way if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

I would use `get_template_directory_uri();` in your functions.php to pass the location to your app.